# Question about counting measure

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, measurable-functions

I want to check if my solution is right. Can someone help me?

Consider the measure space $(\mathbb{R}, 2^{\mathbb{R}}, µ)$ where $µ$ is the counting measure, hence the measure of a set is its cardinality. Show that if $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ is $µ$-integrable then $E = \left \{x ∈ \mathbb{R}|f(x) \neq 0\right \}$ is finite or countably infinite.

So we have $\int_{E}fdµ=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{\phi_N \text{ simple, }\phi_n \leq f}\phi_n d µ=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i µ(A_i)$

If $E$ is infinite than we would have that the sum is infinite and it would not follow integrability.

Is my statement right?

Comment: What are the $A_i$-s? Also what does the condition under the integral mean?

Comment: The $A_i$-s are sets in E, and if you mean "$\phi$ simple and $\phi \leq f$" is the definition of an integral. Since f is integrable we can find a sequence of simple functions $(s_n){n \in \mathbb{N}}$ that converges pointwise to $f$ and such that $\int |s_n| d\mu$ is finite for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, by definition, $\int f d\mu = \lim{n \to \infty} \int s_n d\mu$. I corrected my form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrapositive approach:

If $E$ is not countable then for positive integer $n$ large enough the set: $$E_n=\left\{x\in\mathbb R: |f(x)|>\frac1n\right\}$$ is not countable.

This fact enables us to find distinct elements $x_i$ with $|f(x_i)|>\frac1n$ for $i=1,2,\dots$.

Then: $$\int|f(x)|d\mu\geq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|f(x_i)|=\infty$$ showing that $f$ is not $\mu$-integrable.